# javascript, jquery and jquery-ui gotchas when placing at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

As per the yahoo performance recommendations I tried moving my external js files to the bottom of my page.

as a result some bits of javascript are broken/not working.

im not sure exactly what or why things arent working so I'd like to know for javascript in general and sepecifically for 
jquery and jqueryui of gotchas to be wary of.

Comment: There aren't really any. What errors are you getting and what's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you're using jQuery/jQueryUI code - namely `.ready()` - further up in the document.

Consider putting jQuery back into the head. jQueryUI may work in the bottom if all code calling it is wrapped in a `ready` event.

If you link to jQuery on a CDN, chances are the browser has the file loaded anyway already, and there will be no performance hit from having it in the head.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any inline code in the page that will of course break, even if it's wrapped in $().ready() or similar, since jquery isn't loaded yet. Also, make sure that you're loading them in correct order, so jquery first and then jqueryui etc.